# Grant android app permission to connect to "unverified server"

Tags: android, air

I am trying to put ads in an AIR for Android app. I am hosting the add in an html on my website (which is hosted by godaddy, but I have total control), then loading that html in a StageWebView object (the AIR equivalent of an iframe, kind of) which is in the app.
**This works!**
The ad displays beautifully on the phone, **but** I get this popup each time the app is run: 
*"
The server that the application is connecting to is unverified.

Server: http://www.mywebsite.com/ad.html 

Certificate: 

Issue To:

Common Name: www.google.com

Organizational unit:

Issued By: Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd. [Pretty sure this company owns/is a partner of godaddy]

Organizational unit:



Trust this server and make the connection?

[button 1.]Trust for Session. [button 2.]Cancel

"*
Strangely, the ad is already loaded when this popup appears. If I press cancel, the app does not break (and the ad is clickable!), but the same popup will appear if the app tries to grab a new ad by reloading the ad.html page. Again, the popup appears seemingly AFTER the new ad has loaded! 
This happens if I try to load some other pages, like http://www.questionablecontent.net, but not if I load http://www.stackoverflow.com or a https page like google.
**I cannot tell if it is AIR creating the popup or android, but I'm pretty sure it's Android.**
My android manifest has only two permissions, INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
I have an HTC Incredible 2 on verizon.
I'm open to ANY fix that jsut gets this popup gone!

Answer (score 0):

You are having an issue with a CA certificate.  Probably the CA that verifies your domain is not installed, or at least not visible to Adobe AIR.  I don't know if it will work on Android, but here is a description of how to install the certificate on AIR for OpenSuSE:  http://rachaelandtom.info/content/remove-unverified-server-pop-air